# disable blinking in ace editor for codility code editor

Tags: cursor, ace-editor

https://app.codility.com/demo/take-sample-test/

I need help in disabling the blinking cursor. What is the custom CSS I should use? I am looking at Chrome -> Inspect  I see something like .ace_animate-blinking. If I uncheck that it seems to work, but how to encode that in CSS style sheet?

I am using a chrome extension 'stylebot' to insert custom CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
.ace_cursor {
    animation: none!important
}
```